# What might cause a fluctuating resistance of a generator winding?

Tags: generator, coil, internal-resistance, ohmmeter

Before assembly of a machine that contains a three phase generator I check the resistance between the 3 phases of the generator with an ohmmeter. The generator is kept stationary and the temperature is somewhere around 20 degrees centigrade.

The measurement ensures that the generator has no internal wiring fault.

The success criterion is that the resistance between the different poles is equal and matches the resistance specified by the manufacturer (58 Ohm).

Now I have a generator that has a correct measurement between phase 1-2, but any measurement involving the 3<sup>rd</sup> phase shows me a varying resistance value.

The value jumps around (from 20 to 140 Ohm), converges to the correct resistance value after 20-30 seconds and then starts diverging again.

What could cause this odd behaviour?

Comment: higher or lower, 10% off, double, or factor of 10? What could cause this odd behaviour of the OP that he asks a question and then withholds obvious information? Perhaps he likes seeing people wasting their time on wrong guesses?

Comment: @Neil_UK. If you require more information to answer the question just leave a comment asking that I clarify my question. Why the attitude?

Comment: If it was lower, might guess a short, if higher, might guess an open. Higher and lower, unlikely to have both. I'm sure it's not turning, so generating an EMF which could upset the ohmeter, otherwise you would have volunteered that information, so it's probably stationary. Temperature fluctuations, would expect to be very slow at magnets or coils, but I've have thermal expansion cause intermittents before, both in wires *and* in magnet attachment, the latter could cause generated EMFs. Try percusive investigation, tap it while measuring it and report back.

Comment: "as specified by the manufacturer" - which implies that this part is manufactured elsewhere; And this one does not meet specs. Send it back, to be replaced with one that does meet specs, and let **them** worry about *why.*

Comment: It's likely you are using a digital multimeter for the test.  Since it gives you "snapshot" readings, you now have the additional problem of interpreting what it's showing you.  I'd at least try a different meter, and an analog one if I can find it.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke you should be nice to Neil_UK as you are being paid to do your work, not Neil or anyone else for that matter - most of us do this out of interest...

Comment: "Before assembly" vs. "Now" have the connections to the generator been extended? Is the ohmmeter connection no in a new location. If so, have you checked the additional conductors and connections?

Comment: @SolarMike While a newbie on this SE site, I'm familiar with other SE's. On those other sites it is always disapproved when one has an attitude towards another member (there's even [a rule about it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)). Mind you, I agree that Neil_UK raises valid questions, it's just his tone which is not appropriate for this setting (for any setting actually).

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'll certainly do that. But I'm just curious to find the cause.

Comment: As I see it - you're evidently at work. Your time is the company's money. While you might be curious about the why, it's *probably* not really your job to be, and I'd expect your boss to be possibly a bit upset if you are spending company time with a defective part that is the responsibility of whoever made it to correct. But perhaps you are your own boss, and in that case, you are wasting your time which is costing your company (thus, yourself) money.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, thank you for your concern about my professional wellbeing. However, that is not the scope of this question.

Comment: "Before Assembly".  Was the generator a kit? You had to put it together? Or it was complete, and in installed it, and hooked it up wires to it? Or you rewound it?